Sending a file from File_storage to the front end to be embedded in an iframe using python and flask
For the last few days i have been trying to send a file to my front end to render in an iframe, but i have been struggling with this very much. I am using python and flask.
I haven't provided any code because i have asked this question already and haven't gotten a response that has fixed it.
I have now added my code below:
my route:
@auth.route("/FILE_STORAGE/<string:filename>")
def file_storage(filename):
print(
    "SEND FROM DIRECTORY:",
    current_app.config.get("FILE_STORAGE", "./FILE_STORAGE"),
    "PATH:",
    filename,
)
return send_from_directory(
    current_app.config.get("FILE_STORAGE", "./FILE_STORAGE"),
    filename,
)

Server Logs:
127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2024 10:45:51] "GET /auth/building/view- 
 file/Construction_Originators.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 SEND FROM DIRECTORY: ./FILE_STORAGE PATH: Construction_Originators.pdf
 127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2024 10:45:51] "GET 
 /auth/FILE_STORAGE/Construction_Originators.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 -

HTML:
{% for f in files %}
<tr class="table-row" hx-get="/auth/building/view- 
    file/{{f.name}}" hx-target="#modal-content">
    <td class="table-cell">{{ f.id }}</td>
    <td class="table-cell">{{ f.name }}</td>
    <td class="table-cell">{{ f.building_id }}</td>
    <td class="remove-item-btn" hx-confirm="Are you sure you 
        want to delete this file?"
        hx-get="/auth/building/delete-file" hx-vals='{"file":" 
        {{f.name}}", "building":"{{f.building_id}}"}'
        hx-target="#modal-content">
        &times;
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

View file window:
<iframe src="{{ document|safe }}" type="application/pdf" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>


In general, any static files are accessible in Flask if they are located within the static folder or a subfolder of it. Instructions for this can be found here.
If you use a directory other than the static folder to store your uploaded documents, you will need a separate route through which the respective document is served.
The following example shows you in a simple way how you can serve uploaded documents from a directory using send_from_directory so that they can be displayed in a frame. For this purpose, the URL to the corresponding endpoint is simply created using url_for, which is assigned to the src attribute of the frame via the target attribute with a corresponding click.
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    request,
    send_from_directory,  
    url_for
)
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='your secret here', 
    UPLOAD_FOLDER=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads')
)

os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], exist_ok=True)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    files = os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    return render_template('files/index.html', **locals())

@app.post('/upload')
def upload():
    file = request.files.get('file')
    if file and file.filename != '': 
        file.save(os.path.join(
            app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
            secure_filename(file.filename)
        ))
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
        filename, 
    )

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div>
            <form action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file" />
                <button>Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                {% for file in files -%}
                <li><a class="file-item" href="{{ url_for('download', filename=file) }}" target="frame">{{ file }}</a></li>
                {% endfor -%}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <iframe id="frame" name="frame" style="width: 100%; height: 480px"></iframe>
    </main>

</body>
</html>


Update:
You use a relative path specification with ./FILE_STORAGE. This results in the file not being found.
Use the following code to use an absolute path and fix the problem.
@auth.route("/FILE_STORAGE/<path:filename>")
def file_storage(filename):
    path = os.path.abspath(current_app.config.get("FILE_STORAGE", "./FILE_STORAGE"))
    print(
        "SEND FROM DIRECTORY:",
        path, 
        "PATH:",
        filename,
    )
    return send_from_directory(
        path,
        filename,
    )


I have done as you have suggested but am getting a 404 response on my request.

@user21703142 I've expanded my answer and think that should fix your problem.

Thank you for the help your fix has worked!
